# C# web integration for SCVMM

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, system-center

I have experimented the working with **SCVMM** (System Center Virtual Machine Manager) and Power-Shell to ***create , manage, view status and delete VMs***. But that need some domain knowledge. I wondered how hard it would be to automate the same process through the web application. So then that would easy to manage VMs with less effect and less domain knowledge.

So are there any **web API**'s for SCVMM other than shell script API's.

Are there any DLLs or any other way (SDK, Platform) to approach the manage VM's through the web application.

***I look for a solution for SCVMM 2016 and 2012***

Comment: Curious, why *other than shell script API's*?

Comment: I need to get rid users form shell scripting and develop a UI to do the same thing. So that would be get rid some admin work.

Comment: I misunderstood and still don't understand. You mean managing local VMs or remote ones? You could develop a web app whose server invokes the same shell commands you don't want to them to do manually. And if you run that app and server locally, you will be able to manage local VMs just by wrapping PowerShell in a web app.